# Using Diff on a specific column in a file

Tags: shell-script, scripting, ksh, diff, file-comparison

Will it be possible to use diff on a specific columns in a file?

### file1

```
Something  123 item1
Something  456 item2
Something  768 item3
Something  353 item4
```

### file2

```
Another   123 stuff1
Another   193 stuff2
Another   783 stuff3
Another   353 stuff4
```

### output(Expected)

```
Something  456 item2
Something  768 item3
Another   193 stuff2
Another   783 stuff3
```

I want to `diff` the 2nd column of each file, then, the result will contain the diff-ed column but along with the whole line.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`awk` is a better tool for comparing columns of files. See, for example, the answer to: [compare two columns of different files and print if it matches](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134829/compare-two-columns-of-different-files-and-print-if-it-matches) -- there are similar answers out there for printing lines for matching columns.

Since you want to print lines that *don't* match, we can create an `awk` command that prints the lines in file2 for which column 2 has *not* been seen in file1:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{c[$2]++;next};c[$2] == 0' file1 file2
Another   193 stuff2
Another   783 stuff3
```

As explained similarly by terdon in [the above-mentioned question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134829/compare-two-columns-of-different-files-and-print-if-it-matches),

- `NR==FNR` : NR is the current input line number and FNR the current file's line number. The two will be equal only while the 1st file is being read.
- `c[$2]++; next` : if this is the 1st file, save the 2nd field in the `c` array. Then, skip to the next line so that this is only applied on the 1st file.
- `c[$2] == 0` : the else block will only be executed if this is the second file so we check whether field 2 of this file has already been seen (`c[$2]==0`) and if it has been, we print the line. In `awk`, the default action is to print the line so if `c[$2]==0` is true, the line will be printed.

But you also want the lines from file1 for which column 2 doesn't match in file2. This you can get by simply exchanging their position in the same command:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{c[$2]++;next};c[$2] == 0' file2 file1
Something  456 item2
Something  768 item3
```

So now you can generate the output you want, by using `awk` twice. Perhaps someone with more `awk` expertise can get it done in one pass.

You tagged your question with `/ksh`, so I'll assume you are using korn shell. In `ksh` you can define a function for your diff, say `diffcol2`, to make your job easier:

```
diffcol2()
{
   awk 'NR==FNR{c[$2]++;next};c[$2] == 0' $2 $1      
   awk 'NR==FNR{c[$2]++;next};c[$2] == 0' $1 $2      
}
```

This has the behavior you desire:

```
$ diffcol2 file1 file2
Something  456 item2
Something  768 item3
Another   193 stuff2
Another   783 stuff3
```

Comment: Nice! The NR==FNR trick is nifty, and I like the way it gets wrapped up into a two line function. Magical, but a great explanation of all the complicated bits - you have my vote!

Comment: I had to use awk `-F '\t'` parameter to make it work since I was using CSV files with tab separator. Otherwise a space was considered as a separator for columns. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134829/compare-two-columns-of-different-files-and-print-if-it-matches/134834#134834

Comment: This is really neat. However I have an unusual criticism for this code. Since this makes two calls to `awk` to get the desired output, if we send in redirected streams rather than actual files, it will only perform the first half of the work. I'm curious if (as an awk expert) you could come up with a way to get this done with only one call to `awk`? :D

Answer (score 3):

I don't think diff (even in combination with cut) will be flexible enough to handle this. And it seems as though what you really want is keys in file1 that are not in file2 and vice versa - not strictly a line-by-line diff.  If the input files are big, I would go with perl, but for small files this awk script works for the input provided:

`%cat a.awk`

```
BEGIN {
  while (getline < "file1") {
    line=$0;
    split(line,f," ");
    key=f[2];
    f1[key]=line
  }
  while (getline < "file2") {
    line=$0;
    split(line,f," ");
    key=f[2];
    f2[key]=line
  }
}
END {
  for (c in f1) {
    if (c in f2 == 0) print f1[c]
  }
  for (c in f2) {
    if (c in f1 == 0) print f2[c]
  }
}
```

And this is how you run it (note the trick with /dev/null, since awk expects an input file as a parameter:

```
%awk -f a.awk /dev/null
Something  456 item2
Something  768 item3
Another   193 stuff2
Another   783 stuff3
```

Comment: if the keys are duplicated in one file, only last line with that key is printed; invocation for different files is difficult

Answer (score 0):

Something like this does the trick in one pass:

```
$ awk '{t[$2]=t[$2]$0"\n";NR==FNR?a[$2]=1:b[$2]=1}END{for(i in t)if(a[i]!=b[i])printf"%s",t[i]}' file1 file2
Another   193 stuff2
Something  456 item2
Something  768 item3
Another   783 stuff3
```

Explanation:

- for each line:

  - `{t[$2]=t[$2]$0"\n";` concatenate all lines having the same key in the table `t` indexed by that key,
  - `NR==FNR?a[$2]=1:b[$2]=1}` if the key was in the first file, put it in `a` table, otherwise in `b` table;
- `END` at the end:

  - `{for(i in t)` for each key in the table `t`:

    - `if(a[i]!=b[i])` if the key was present only in one file:

      - `printf"%s",t[i]}` print all lines with that key.

This works also if the keys are duplicated (prints all lines that has no key in another file), however the order of lines is not preserved (the lines are printed in lexicographical order of keys).