# compare two csv files and fetch matching data into a new csv file

Tags: text-processing, csv

I have two csv files with similar content/data.

---

**file1.csv**

```
ADIS
BAP3
Mercury_System
nxh-2003
DR_FeatureUP_PT
```

---

**file2.csv**

```
ADIS,projects.adis
EcoSystems,projects.ecosystems
em1xxxsw,projects.em1xxxsw
BAP3,projects.bap3
Dirana4,projects.dirana4
Mercury_System,projects.mercury_system
nxh-2003,projects.nxh-2003
DocStore,projects.docstore
DR_FeatureUP_PT,projects.dr_featureup_pt
```

---

Desired **output.csv**

```
ADIS,projects.adis
BAP3,projects.bap3
Mercury_System,projects.mercury_system
nxh-2003,projects.nxh-2003
DR_FeatureUP_PT,projects.dr_featureup_pt
```

---

Please let me know the command used for this type of query.

Comment: What kind of query are you trying to do?  Right now we just have 2 input files from you.

Comment: see also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134829/compare-two-columns-of-different-files-and-print-if-it-matches

Comment: @EricRenouf i have given two input files, so a query/command/sed/awk/grep anything should comapre these two inout files and get a data which is similar like the one i gave in output

Comment: Yes, but how should the output be generated from those two files? Explain in words. Do you just want the 1,2,4,5,and 7th lines from file? Are you looking for `grep -Ff file1 file2`? What if file2 contains a `ADISBADIS`, should that match `ADIS`? You need to tell us what you need instead of expecting us to guess.

Comment: file1.csv contains 118 rows , file2.csv contains 2500 rows with 2 columns

My requirement is the code/script should match both the csv files and fetch the matched row in a new file. I even tried grep -Ff file1 file2 but no use, there will be only single string with the same in both files. I am running GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) to join the two CSV data sets on the named field `ADIS`:

```bash
$ mlr --csv join -j ADIS -f file1.csv file2.csv
ADIS,projects.adis
BAP3,projects.bap3
Mercury_System,projects.mercury_system
nxh-2003,projects.nxh-2003
DR_FeatureUP_PT,projects.dr_featureup_pt
```

If `ADIS` is not actually a field name and the two CSV files are *header-less*, then use the following instead (reads the input as header-less CSV and uses the field number instead of the field name in the `join` operation):

```bash
$ mlr --csv -N join -j 1 -f file1.csv file2.csv
ADIS,projects.adis
BAP3,projects.bap3
Mercury_System,projects.mercury_system
nxh-2003,projects.nxh-2003
DR_FeatureUP_PT,projects.dr_featureup_pt
```

The output of this second command *looks* the same as that of the first command.  However, the first line in each file in no longer interpreted as a header line but as a record of data fields.

This would work regardless of whether the input data files are DOS or Unix text files.

Answer (score 0):

Using grep;

```
grep -Ff file1.csv file2.csv > outfile.csv
```

using awk

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{seen[$0]++;next} ($1 in seen)' file1.csv file2.csv > outfile.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with a simple script to execute in the shell. Try with this:

```
while read i; do grep $i ./file2.csv >> output.csv; done < file1.csv
```

It will create a new file called output.csv with the result that you are expecting for. You need to run it on the folder where you have stored both files file1.csv and file2.csv.

Answer (score 0):

Using Bash process substitution, you can sort the files and then "join" them.

```
join -t, <(sort file1.csv) <(sort file2.csv) > output.csv
```