# Comparing two files and writing mismatched rows along with mismatched columns. Pointing out the mismatched columns is my main problem statement

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, diff, file-comparison

I got a requirement where I need to compare two files wrt to each columns and write the corresponding difference in another file along with some identification showing mismatched columns. **Pointing out the mismatched columns is my main problem statement.** For example we have files like:

```
File 1

1|piyush|bangalore|dev
1|piyush|bangalore|QA
2|pankaj|bangalore|dev
3|rohit|delhi|QA

File 2

1|piyush|bangalore|QA
1|piyush|bangalore|QA
2|pankaj|bangalore|dev
3|rohit|bangalore|dev
```

The expected output file looks somewhat like.

```
File 1
1|piyush|bangalore|**dev**
File 2 
1|piyush|bangalore|**QA**
File 1
3|rohit|**delhi**|**QA**
File 2
3|rohit|**bangalore**|**dev**
```

I want to achieve something like this where i can see the mismatched columns as well along with mismatched rows. I have tried

`diff File1 File2 > Diff_File`

But this is giving me only the mismatched records or rows. **I am not getting any way to point out the mismatched columns as well.** Please help me out if its possible to do is using shell script or awk command as i am very new to this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [compare two columns of different files and print if it matches](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134829/compare-two-columns-of-different-files-and-print-if-it-matches)

Comment: Hi Yaron, thanks for the link but that is not a duplicate, if you can please read my whole explanation of my problem statement. I need to compare all the columns for each rows and get the diff file where i can point out the unmatched column. Pointing out the unmatched column is my main problem statement

Comment: @piyush, there's no `3|rohit|**delhi**|**QA**` row within your input files. Update your 
expected output

Comment: Hi @RomaPerekhrest sorry and thanks for pointing out.  I have updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Python*** 3.x solution:

***diff_marked.py*** script:

```
import sys

file1_name = sys.argv[1]
file2_name = sys.argv[2]

with open(file1_name, 'r') as f1, open(file2_name, 'r') as f2:
    f1_lines = f1.readlines()  # list of lines of File1
    f2_lines = f2.readlines()  # list of lines of File2

    for k,l in enumerate(f1_lines):
        f1_fields = l.strip().split('|')  # splitting a line into fields by separator '|'
        if k < len(f2_lines) and f2_lines[k]:
            has_diff = False
            f2_fields = f2_lines[k].strip().split('|')
            for i,f in enumerate(f1_fields):
                if f != f2_fields[i]:    # comparing respective lines 'field-by-field' between two files
                    f1_fields[i] = '**' + f + '**'  # wrapping differing fields
                    f2_fields[i] = '**' + f2_fields[i] + '**'
                    has_diff = True

        if has_diff:
            print(f1.name)  # print file name
            print('|'.join(f1_fields))
            print(f2.name)
            print('|'.join(f2_fields))
```

***Usage:*** (you may have another python version, the current case has been tested on *python 3.5*)

```
python3.5 diff_marked.py File1 File2 > diff_output
```

---

`diff_output` contents:

```
File1
1|piyush|bangalore|**dev**
File2
1|piyush|bangalore|**QA**
File1
3|rohit|**delhi**|**QA**
File2
3|rohit|**bangalore**|**dev**
```

Comment: Thanks RomanPerekhrest for the answer. I was looking for shell script. As of now i am using dwdiff utility to do my work. I will except your answer as this is a good solution for the stated problem.