# Matching columns of different csv files, not working when column value is different length

Tags: awk, csv

I'm matching 3 columns between a large csv file and a small csv file and writing these to an output file. There are many questions on here that have helped but I can't find the answer to the specific problem I'm running into. When the column entry is shorter, it's not finding the match.

My solution is based on the solution here: [compare two columns of different files and print if it matches](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134829/compare-two-columns-of-different-files-and-print-if-it-matches)

The matching columns should be small1 == large120002, small2 == large120003, small3 == large120004.

What I am trying...

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{c[$1,$2,$3]++;next};c[$120002,$120003,$120004] > 0' small.csv large.csv > output.csv
```

This works, sort of. This excludes those rows where large120002 is an int less than 9 characters in length. (So far values for large120002 are 7-9 characters long).

Ever run into this problem before? 
If possible I would like to stick with an awk solution.

Comment: Thanks for deleting that comma bro. 6th grade English class I was known for my run-on sentences. Solid edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out it was a casting issue, so I added 0 to the columns to make sure both were being treated the same by awk.

With the help of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808971/casting-to-int-in-awk

This wound up working..

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{c[$1+0,$2,$3]++;next};c[$120002+0,$120003,$120004] > 0' small.csv large.csv > output.csv
```